# Offline Desktop Client for OpenStreetMap on Linux

Tags: linux, offline, maps, openstreetmap

The OpenStreetMap wiki [shows many, many clients](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Software/Desktop) and I am not sure how to navigate it all.

I would want the features and appearance of the client to resemble the features and appearance of the [online version](http://wwww.openstreetmap.org/) as close as possible.

To be specific:

- Offline
- Must work natively on linux
- Querying
- Navigation (car, bicycle, foot)
- Map layers
- Decent graphics
- Easy setup
- Synchronize data

Does anyone know of an offline client for OpenStreetMap on Linux that they love?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use [Cruiser](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Cruiser). Its platform is Java so it will work on **Linux**.

> #### Features
>
> - Offline detailed vector maps (Mapsforge)
> - Map file chooser
> - Add multiple maps
> - Render theme file chooser
> - Render theme style with overlays selection
> - Render theme SVG graphics
> - Variable text size of vector maps
> - Online maps (MapQuest, Mapnik, Cycle Map, Transport Map, Humanitarian)
> - Adjust scale of map display
> - Bookmarks
> - Copy to clipboard (latitude, longitude)
> - Status bar with latitude, longitude, zoom level
> - Compatible with OpenAndroMaps
>
> #### Navigation
>
> - Offline routing (GraphHopper)
> - Graph chooser
> - Graphs creation
> - Waypoints management
> - Drag waypoints
> - Reverse route
> - Export route (GPX)
>
> #### Tools
>
> - Import (GPX, GeoJSON)
> - Go to position with coordinates / zoom
> - Measure
> - Map screenshot
> - Reload map
> - Map info
>
> [image: Atlas User Interface on Linux]

Comment: It is now called "[Cruiser](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Cruiser)".

Comment: Thanks, @GolarRamblar - answer updated accordingly